integral of the $n$-th power of a function and its distribution
Let $f_1,f_2$ be two measurable functions on $(0,1)$. If thre exists an constant $c>0$ such that
$$\int_0^1 f_1^nd m =\int_0^1 f_2^n dm   =O((cn)^n) ,$$
then are $f_1$ and $f_2$ equimeasurable?
